# Image not updating on WordPress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I developed a WordPress theme, and  I have a question.

I have a logo on my website. When I trying upload a new logo, and I refreshing the page, the logo does not change. I still see the old logo. The logo is changing only when I open the image link.

How can I solve it?

Comment: what is that? Paste the snippet that is not working?

Comment: I just using the simple <img> tag to get my image.

Comment: You need to use filters to change the image. All the code should be pasted in the functions.php file.

Comment: My img code is on index.php not on functions.php, I am uploading the image to the server without wp-admin panel

Comment: Yup every backend code is to be pasted in either function.php or you have to include the custom php file in functions.php file. Which every file you are working with functions.php is the heart of wordpress for plugin developers.

Comment: Have you tried `CTRL+F5` to clear that browser cache

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes. Only when I open the logo link, The logo is updating on the website.

Comment: Put your code snippet that is used for unloading.

Comment: Looks like caching issues trying clearing browser cache or in case your using WordPress caching plugin try clearing that !